# Create a capitalized macro token using \csname

Tags: macros, expansion, capitalization

Two things I understand and one thing I don't:

I often use `\csname` to create user-defined tokens. For instance, the following code uses `\expandafter` to expand everything between `\csname` and `\endcsname` before `\gdef`ing the result:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname #1\endcsname{Here is #1 printed.}%
}

\begin{document}
\mycommand{abc} % Creates a macro \abc
Demonstration: \abc % Prints Demonstration: Here is abc printed.
\end{document}
```

I wanted to do something similar by using `\mycommand{abc}` to create a macro `\Abc` (note the capital letter). Unfortunately, `\uppercase` cannot be used inside `\csname`. (I'm guessing some parts expand to TeX primitives?) But I found a somewhat related answer from Heiko Oberdiek (http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2006-02/msg01220.html) and created the following, which I don't entirely understand.

It should create a new uppercase token, and I think it is working, since I can then `\let` it to another macro and it does not error.

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{% 
  \uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter\csname #1}\endcsname% Creates token 
}%
\def\temp{if it worked}
\let\Abc\temp% Now \Abc expands to something other than \relax

\begin{document}
\mycommand{abc}% Creates \Abc
This lets you see \Abc.% Prints This lets you see if it worked.
\end{document}
```

So my question is: how can I create an uppercase token and define the expansion *at the same time*? (Basically, I want to combine both of the above approaches.) Here are two ways I have tried (both return Error: extra \endcsname).

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{% 
  \expandafter\gdef%   I think this tries to do \gdef\uppercase = bad 
  \uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter\csname #1}\endcsname{the macro #1 expanded}%  
}%
\mycommand{abc}
Use \Abc. % Should print Use the macro abc expanded.
```

or

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{% 
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter{% 
  \uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter\csname #1}\endcsname}{the macro #1 expanded}% 
}%
\mycommand{abc}
Use \Abc. % Should print Use the macro abc expanded.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to isolate the first token in `#1` from the rest and uppercase it; the fact that `\uppercase` doesn't expand anything and puts back the token list into the input stream after its operation can be exploited in the following way:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\mycommandaux#1\relax}
\def\mycommandaux#1#2\relax{%
  \uppercase{\expandafter\gdef\csname #1}#2\endcsname{the macro #1#2 expanded}%
}
\mycommand{abc}
\show\Abc
```

Of course an empty argument to `\mycommand` will result in an error.

If you want to provide a definition, say

```
\mycommand{abc}{Something else}
```

to be equivalent to `\def\Abc{Something else}`, just leave out the tokens after `\endcsname`

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\mycommandaux#1\relax}
\def\mycommandaux#1#2\relax{%
  \uppercase{\expandafter\gdef\csname #1}#2\endcsname
}
\mycommand{abc}{Something else}
\show\Abc
```

---

The command `\uppercase` is a bit stranger than other TeX primitives. Indeed the `<general text>` it requires as argument first does a travel down TeX's stomach to be "regurgitated" after each character token has been transformed using the `\uccode` vector: if a character has positive `\uccode`, TeX will transform it into that character (the category code is unchanged). So, for instance, TeX is setup so that `` \uccode`a=`A `` and so an `a` becomes an `A` after regurgitation. Non character token are left unchanged and *no* expansion is performed.

Here's the working in slow motion (first version).

1. `\mycommand{abc}`
   Here `#1` is `abc`
2. `\mycommandaux abc\relax`
   Here `#1` is `a` and `#2` is `bc` (argument `#2` is delimited by `\relax`, while `#1` is undelimited, so the only first token is grabbed)
3. `\uppercase{\expandafter\gdef\csname a}bc\endcsname {the macro abc expanded}`
   Tex *executes* the `\uppercase` and puts back

   ```
   \expandafter\gdef\csname A
   ```

   in the input stream.
4. `\expandafter\gdef\csname Abc\endcsname{the macro abc expanded}`
5. `\gdef\Abc{the macro abc expanded}`

Et voilà.

---

A variant with `\newcommand` instead of `\gdef`, that makes it easy to define macros with arguments:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\mycommandaux#1\relax}
\def\mycommandaux#1#2\relax{%
  \uppercase{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1}#2\endcsname
}
\mycommand{abc}{Something else}
\show\Abc

\mycommand{uvw}[1]{Something else with #1}
\show\Uvw
```

With `\gdef` the standard parameter text should be used.

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\mycommandaux#1\relax}
\def\mycommandaux#1#2\relax{%
  \uppercase{\expandafter\gdef\csname #1}#2\endcsname
}
\mycommand{abc}{Something else}
\show\Abc

\mycommand{uvw}#1{Something else with #1}
\show\Uvw
```

Comment: Thank you. I adapted this to the (more complicated) problem at home and it works beautifully. Voting as answer simply because it has syntax close to what I was using before, so I can follow it. Clearly \uppercase has behavior far different than what I expected.

Comment: That was my first idea, too, but somehow I turned it more complicated while implementing it ;-) You shouldn't code TeX while correcting your PhD thesis ;-)

Comment: Mmh, I like it but.. what if I need `\Abc` to take arguments? I cannot write `\endcsname#1` because `#1` has another meaning here :\

Comment: This gets me an `Illegal parameter number in definition of \mycommandaux`. (I have to say that I am doing this from inside a `\newcommand`, so that my base level already is `##1` and I am shifting to `###1`)..

Comment: @iago-lito You have to use `#1` at definition time. I added the variants.

Comment: @iago-lito With `\newcommand*` the macro will *not* accept multiple paragraphs as argument.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that `\uppercase` is not expandable. You can't use it with `\expandafter`. I would expand the argument first, as good measure, then read the first letter using a second, internal macro, then use `\uppercase` to change that letter. Finally a second internal macro reads the new uppercase letter and the rest of the name and makes the definition. The original name can also be passed as a third argument if required:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{% 
    \begingroup
    \edef\@tempa{#1}%
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\@mycommand\@tempa\@nnil{#1}%
}
\def\@mycommand#1{%
    \uppercase{\@@mycommand{#1}}%
}
\def\@@mycommand#1#2\@nnil#3{%
    \global\@namedef{#1#2}{the macro #3 expanded}%%
}
\makeatother
\mycommand{abc}
\show\Abc
```

Comment: Wow, this is entirely too clever for me! So in pseudo-code: the first part ends up executing \@mycommand abc\@nnil{abc} before the group closes.

The second part uses \@mycommand to bite off the a and results in: \uppercase{\@@mycommand{a}}bc\@nnil{abc}

How is it that \@@mycommand does not mind the double }}? I don't understand what happens next. Does \uppercase do its thing, or does \@@mycommand?

Comment: @Natalie: `\uppercase` is executed first, takes `\@@mycommand{a}` (because it's in `{..}` after it) and turns all tokens to their uppercase version. Macro are unchanged, afterwards it places the whole thing back, i.e. `\@@mycommand{A}` is placed before `bc\@nnil{abc}`, then `\@@mycommand` reads the `{A}` as first argument and everything to the next `\@nnil` as second. The `{abc}` afterwards is taken as third argument.

Comment: Very neat! Thanks for the explanation. Using the fact that `\uppercase` doesn't expand or change macros is a good trick.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good example of why LuaTeX is useful.

```
\def\defineuppercase#1%
    {\ctxcommand{defineuppercase("#1")}}

\startluacode
  function commands.defineuppercase(s)
      local upper = string.gsub(s, "^%l", string.upper)
      context.setgvalue(upper)
  end
\stopluacode

\defineuppercase{one}{Something}

\show\One
\end
```

I am using ConTeXt MkIV, but the code can be easily translated to LaTeX as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this with [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/). So after defining `\mycommand{abc}`, and `\mycommand{dbc}`, you can use `\Abc`, and `\Def` to get:

[image]

### Note:

- The code below is not complete in that it only converts the letters `a,...,f` to `A,...,F`, but extending it should *not* be too difficult.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{a}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{a}{A}[\newMacroName]}{}%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{b}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{b}{B}[\newMacroName]}{}%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{c}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{c}{C}[\newMacroName]}{}%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{d}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{d}{D}[\newMacroName]}{}%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{e}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{e}{E}[\newMacroName]}{}%
    \IfBeginWith{#1}{f}{\StrSubstitute{#1}{f}{F}[\newMacroName]}{}%
    % ... complete this ...
    \expandafter\gdef\csname \newMacroName\endcsname{Here is #1 printed.}%
}%

\begin{document}
\mycommand{abc} % Creates a macro \Abc
Demonstration: \Abc % Prints Demonstration: Here is abc printed.


\mycommand{dbc} % Creates a macro \Dbc
Demonstration: \Dbc % Prints Demonstration: Here is abc printed.
\end{document}
```