# \newcommand and name of command

Tags: macros, glossaries

I would like to automatically generate commands like

```
\newcommand{\Air}{\gls{air}}
\newcommand{\Earth}{\gls{earth}}
...
```

to use with `glossaries` package, without using `\newcommand` for every entry of the glossary. Is this possible and how?

Stating this differently, is it possible to automatically create commands of the type `\Abbr` where `Abbr` is the `uppercase` form of the `abbr` argument in

```
\newglossaryentry{abbr}{name=...}
```

Comment: You could simply wrap the `newglossaryentry` macro in something that defines two new macros (upper and lowercase) and then does the original `newglossaryentry`?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you want `\Abbr` to print the uppercased contents of the `name` field of the `abbr` glossary entry, this is a way.

I've used the trick described by egreg in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57554/27635) to define `\Abbr`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\let\oldglossaryentry\newglossaryentry
\renewcommand{\newglossaryentry}[2]{%
\def\tempname##1##2\relax{%
  \uppercase{\expandafter\gdef\csname ##1}##2\endcsname{\MakeUppercase{\glsentrytext{##1##2}}}%
}%
\tempname#1\relax%
\oldglossaryentry{#1}{#2}}

\newglossaryentry{abbr}
{
  name={abbreviation},
  description={description of abbreviation},
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\Abbr

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aah, the uppercase group can end halfway through the csname, that's good to know. Makes sense, actually. Thanks :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason you are going through an extra layer of macro? That is, it would work just as wel if you left out `tempname` and used `\tempnameaux{#1}` right before adding the old glossary entry, wouldn't it?

Comment: @RoelofSpijker You are right. Answer edited. Thanks for pointing it out :-)

Comment: I don't need to `\MakeUppercase` it, but this answer is what I was looking for. I just need the uppercase form in order to prevent clash with other commands that may be already defined. The text will be in smallcaps so `\gls{##1##2} will do. I wanted to emulate the `leipzig` package behaviour in all that. Thanks.

Comment: @Stefano Happy that helped. Adapt it to your needs, anyway I would suggest `\textsc{\glsentrytext{##1##2}}`.

Comment: Not all the abbreviations are in small caps, so I can't `\textsc` them all in the macro, but thank you for suggesting it!

Answer (score 7):

As extension of Roelof's answer:

One can use the LaTeX helper macros `\@car` and `\@cdr` to extract the 1st letter of a given name, for example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*\newfloat@capitalize[2]{%
  \edef\newfloat@tempa{\gdef\noexpand#1{\@car#2\@nil}}%
  \uppercase\expandafter{\newfloat@tempa}%
  \edef\newfloat@tempa{%
    \noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand#1{\@cdr#2\@nil}}%
  \newfloat@tempa}
\newcommand*\mynewglos[2]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#1}{#2}%
  \@namedef{#1}{\gls{#1}}%
  \newfloat@capitalize\@tempa{#1}%
  \@namedef{\@tempa}{\Gls{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries{}
\begin{document}
\mynewglos{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,description={solution able to conduct electric current}}
\gls{electrolyte} or \electrolyte{} or \Gls{electrolyte} or \Electrolyte
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Some notes:

- `\@car` and `\@cdr` and their usage are documented in the LaTeX source.
- `\newfloat@capitalize` is taken from my `newfloat` package and defines the 1st argument (=command) to the 2nd argument (=name) but with 1st letter capitalized. (It is defined with `\providecommand` so using the `newfloat` package in the document does not make any harm. As alternative one could give that macro a new name, or integrate it into the definition of `\mynewglos` which would eliminate the need of a helper macro.)
- The (helper) macro, in this case `\@tempa` will be defined globally. This is caused by the usage of the LaTeX helper macro `\g@addto@macro` which has no companion macro `\l@addto@macro` which does the same thing but locally. (But `\l@addto@macro` is offered by many LaTeX packages, e.g. the KOMA-Script document classes.) As an alternative one could use the eTeX primitive `\unexpanded` for doing the same thing without helper macro, see the definition of `\l@addto@macro` provided by KOMA-Script as an example.

Answer (score 6):

Creating a macro from a parameter where the first letter has to be capitalized turns out to be extremely difficult (or I am doing something wrong). It comes down to the fact that `\uppercase` is not expandable. And `\uppercase{\csname #1\endcsname}` would capitalize the entire word...

The easiest thing that I can think of is to give the uppercase word as a parameter as well. That is, you could use the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\def\mynewglos#1#2#3{%
  \newglossaryentry{#1}{#3}%
  \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{\gls{#1}}%
  \expandafter\def\csname #2\endcsname{\Gls{#1}}%
}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries{}
\begin{document}
\mynewglos{electrolyte}{Electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,description={solution able to conduct electric current}}
\gls{electrolyte} or \electrolyte{} or \Gls{electrolyte} or \Electrolyte
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Note that this defines `\Abbr` as the capitalized version `\Gls` instead of the regular version. You can simply change that in the definition containing `#2`. If it is not required, you can also remove the lowercase definitions by removing the definition containing `#1`.

If someone has a good way to define `\Abbr` from a macro where only `abbr` is passed as an argument, I would very much like to see it :)