# build a capitalized CS from a lowercase string and to give it a definition

Tags: macros

Is it possible to build a capitalized Control Sequence from an argument of lowercase string and to give it a definition?
   I tested two codes, but both didn't work well.

code1:

```
\def\makecs#1#2{%
     \expandafter\def\csname \uppercase{#1}\endcsname{#2}
}
\makecs{macroname}{definition}
\MACRONAME
```

code2:

```
\def\makeCS#1#2{%
    \expandafter\def\uppercase{\csname #1\endcsname}{#2}
}
\makeCS{macro}{def}
\MACRO
```

Now I understand why they didn't work well, but I have no ideas for alternative solution. What should I do to build a capitalized Control Sequence from an argument of lowercase string and to give it a definition?

Comment: I found the same question after I posted my question. I add the link of that: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57551/create-a-capitalized-macro-token-using-csname

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\uppercase` is not expandable. Therefore it does not expand inside `\csname`, which then chokes on `\uppercase` in the name.

Also `\expandafter\def\uppercase` cannot expand `\uppercase`, thus `\expandafter` has no effect and the remaining `\def\uppercase` would change the definition of `\uppercase`.

There `\uppercase` should be given outside:

```
\def\makecs#1#2{%
     \uppercase{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname}{#2}%          
}
\makecs{macroname}{definition}
\MACRONAME
```

First `\uppercase` is called, which converts the lowercase tokens in `#1` to upper case (the other tokens are command tokens). Then `\def` is called with the upper case letters in place.

Step by step:

```
 \makecs{macroname}{definition}
 \uppercase{\expandafter\def\csname macroname\endcsname}{definition}
 \expandafter\def\csname MACRONAME\endcsname{definition}
 \def\MACRONAME{definition}
```

Comment: Thanks for hte useful answer. I have posted an extension of this question on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349629/build-and-use-a-capitalized-cs-from-a-lowercase-string. In case you know how to solve it, I'ld love to hear it.