Dynamically create a new environment with an uppercased argument
I'm using amsthm to create theorems. Whenever I create a new theorem (using \newtheorem), I need to create an alternative environment, with the same name but an uppercase first letter. For example, I have:
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
\newenvironment{Theo}[1][]
  {\needspace{3\baselineskip}\traitfalse\begin{theo}[#1]\leavevmode}
  {\end{theo}\traittrue}

I want to automate this. I tried to adapt https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57554/52638 like this:
\newcommand{\newTheorem}[1]{\newTheoremaux#1\relax}
\def\newTheoremaux#1#2\relax{%
  \uppercase{\expandafter\newenvironment\csname #1}#2\endcsname[1][]%
  {\needspace{3\baselineskip}\traitfalse\begin{#1#2}[##1]\leavevmode}%
  {\end{#1#2}\traittrue}%
}

but I get the following error: ./m33.tex:67: Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again>  \Theo  l.67 \newTheorem{theo}.

I probably don't understand your use case fully. Are the theo and Theo environments supposed to share the same counter? If that's the case, could you execute first \newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section] and then, say, \newtheorem{Theo}[theo]{Auxiliary Theorem}?

Here's how you can support all possibilities of \newtheorem.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{needspace}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewTheorem}{momo}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}
   {% no parent counter
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {% no sibling
      \newtheorem {#1} {#3}
     }
     {% sibling
      \newtheorem {#1} [#2] {#3} 
     }
   }
   {% parent counter
    \newtheorem {#1} {#3} [#4]
   }
  \arkandias_newthm_extra:ne {#1} { \str_uppercase:f { \str_head:n {#1} } \str_tail:n {#1} }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \arkandias_newthm_extra:nn
 {% #1 = original name, #2 = uppercased name
  \NewDocumentEnvironment {#2} {o}
   {
    \needspace{3\baselineskip}
    \traitfalse
    \IfNoValueTF{##1}{\begin{#1}}{\begin{#1}[##1]}
    \leavevmode
   }
   {\end{#1}\traittrue}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \arkandias_newthm_extra:nn {ne}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newif\iftrait % ????

\NewTheorem{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
No break
\end{theo}

\begin{Theo}
\begin{itemize}
\item With break
\end{itemize}
\end{Theo}

\end{document}



Took me quite some time to understand the syntax (I'm not familiar with expl3 at all), but this is perfect (much better than what I intended to do)!
